# IIS - Service Unavailable

Tags: iis, web

Recently we are facing "Service Unavailable" while opening our web reports url in internet explorer.
Restarting the IIS service resolves the issue but didn't found any logs/errors in event viewer to track what is causing IIS to fail.

Is there any other way to troubleshoot this?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually help you out SO need more information but following is more common cause.

1. There is no enough memory for application to run when it try to start. If there are multiple application in your IIS then it cause such issue as other application took priority so memory consume by them.
2. Your application has some un-handle exception that cause your application to shutdown and sometime it cause worker process to stop.
3. If your application is .NET based ( This is not the case with you because after IIS restart it runs successfully ) then .NET Runtime Version conflict also create such problem.